# server error inserting image into google sheets

Tags: image, insert, server, google-sheets, blob

I continually get this error:

"We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

When trying to run the following code:

```
function insertSig(){
  //get the folder
  var sigFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFoldersByName("Signature").next()
  //get the file
  var sig = sigFolder.getFilesByName("Signature.png").next()
  //get the blob data
  var sigBlob = sig.getBlob();

  //access the sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()

  //insert image into sheet
  sheet.insertImage(sigBlob, 1, 1)// throws error 
}
```

I don't believe its an issue with the blob data as I have been able to log and print data from the blob and create a new file in other places on my google drive using the blob data.

I've also been able to access and edit other data on the spreadsheet.

I'm not sure what else to test/try and i'm quite stumped.

Thanks in advance,
 -L

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.

After further testing with multiple locations and images, I found that the image was too big to be inserted.

I didn't test to find the max, but 1321 x 1002 was too big.

Regards,